# Calling pageload after some operation

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net

I have an aspx.cs file with the following code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //Some code
}
protected void Removeabc(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //Some code

}
```

In the last line of Removeabc i want to reload the page and call Page_Load again. Please help me on how to do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
```

It will redirect you to the same page and call Page_Load().

Answer (score 2):

To reload the page, use

```
Response.Redirect(Request.Url.ToString())
```

It will call the Page_Load on that reload.

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap that logic into a third method which can be called from both handlers:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //Some code
   DoSomeCleverStuff();
}
protected void Removeabc(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //Some code
   DoSomeCleverStuff();
}
private void DoSomeCleverStuff() {
    // Clever stuff
}
```

It is good practice not to put heavy logic/code into event handlers in C#. Extract the core logic out into either another method or class so that the code can be re-used elsewhere throughout the class/application.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect to this page using `Response.Redirect(Request.Url.ToString())` or if you only want the code in `Page_Load` to execute you can call `Page_Load(null,null)`